# Bootstrap dropdown-menu on row below

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using wordpress with roots as its theme to build a website.

I have been trying to get the dropdown-menu to display the children of each parent on a row below on hover.

Has anyone else done this before or any advice on where to start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my CSS gave the desired effect

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: -webkit-inline-box;

}
```